# jQuery DataTables Accessibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, accessibility

On the last couple of days, I've tried to make jQuery DataTables a bit more accessible.

The functionality I needed was to be able to focus on every row in the table using the tab and select the focused row using the Enter / Return key press.
The selected row afterward can be edited (no inline editing is needed).

After endless search with no success finding the hint to nail that specific requirement, and since I know accessibility (as much as it's important) can be a real pain I've decided to post the solution I came with.

**Step one:**
When defining the dataTable object add the following function:

```
var table = $('#myTable').dataTable({
    "fnCreatedRow": function( nRow ) {
        $(nRow).attr("tabindex", "0");
        $(nRow).attr("aria-selected", "false");
    },
    ....
});
```

The above function will add tabindex="0" attribute to the row element allowing it to be selected using the tab.

**Step two:**
Bind an keypress event to the table row to catch the keyboard Enter key:

```
$('#myTable').on('keypress', 'tr', function (event) {
    var key = event.which;
    if(key == 13)  // the enter key code
    {
        var target = $(event.target);
        if (target.is("td") || target.is("tr")) {
            if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
                $(this).removeClass('selected');
                $(this).attr("aria-selected", "false");
            }
         }
         else{
             oTable = $('#myTable').dataTable();
             $('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
             $(this).addClass('selected');
             $(this).attr("aria-selected", "true");
         }
    }
});
```

**Step three:**
Bind an click event to the table row to catch the mouse click:

```
$('#myTable').on('click', 'tr', function (event) { {
    var target = $(event.target);
    if (target.is("td") || target.is("tr")) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
            $(this).attr("aria-selected", "false");
        }
    }
    else{
        oTable = $('#myTable').dataTable();
        $('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $(this).attr("aria-selected", "true");
    }
});
```

Do any one else have a better solution that I have missed?

Liron

Comment: This is not a question and your "answer" is not a good answer for any accessibility question. I suggest you post your question i.e. what accessibility problem are you trying to solve for data tables (believe me there are more than one) and then your solution and let others help you arrive at a good solution.

Comment: This is very generic, and it does not solve "all" accessibility issues, but thank you for the contribution.

Comment: @unobf, Thanks for your comment, I've rephrased the post, and also specified what I aimed to achieve.

Comment: Have you tested this with a screen reader? I fear it will not work.

Comment: @unobf, the dataTable already supports screen readers.
I only aimed to add the ability to use the tab in order to moe between rows.

Comment: did you test your selection functionality with a screen reader?

Comment: @unobf, Yes I've checked it with NVDA and when moving using the tab button the new row is being read by the app.

Comment: In order to enhance what you have here, I would suggest adding in some ARIA (aria-selected, for example), so when you are add/removing class, also add/remove the appropriate ARIA attributes. This will go a long way in helping the accessibility.

Comment: @cfnerd. Thanks for the great suggestion.
I've edited the code above and added the aria-selected on row creation and on selection changed.